# c# I have a very confusing InvalidCastException error

Tags: c#, winforms, math, streamreader, classcastexception

I'm having an error that says "invalid cast exception" whenever I try to open one specific form in a program i'm making. The code here takes data from text files to put it into a data grid view. It also makes calculations to put averages in the data grid view. I'm getting an error that seems to involve a variable called "skiTime", which is an average of 3 other variables: "skiTime1" "skiTime2" and "skiTime3". The numbers are decimals, e.g. 23.22, or 54.32, etc.

When I try to load this form, the program closes and Visual studio highlights this line:

```
decimal skiTimeDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(skiTime[i]);
```

I don't know what part of the code the error is in, it could literally be anywhere since my code is so messy, I basically just pulled from random tutorials, and answers to questions I asked here because I need it done for school and don't know c#. Here's the full part of the code that I think might relate to this error.

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("groups.txt", false))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < skiTimeID.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < quizID.Count; j++)
                    {
                        for (int l = 0; l < pupilDetailsID.Count; l++)
                        {
                            if (skiTimeID[i] == quizID[j] && quizID[j] == pupilDetailsID[l])
                            {
                                string fullPupilRecord = pupilDetailsID[l] + "~" + pupilDetailsFirstName[l] + "~" + pupilDetailsSurname[l] + "~" + pupilDetailsClass[l]
                                + "~" + pupilDetailsNumber[l] + "~" + skiTime[i] + "~" + quizScore[j] + "~" + quizPercentage[j];



                                int quizScoreNumber = Convert.ToInt32(quizScore[j]);
                                decimal skiTimeDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(skiTime[i]);

                                if (quizScoreNumber >= 3 && skiTimeDecimal <= 40)
                                {
                                    groupLevel = "Advanced";
                                }

                                else if (quizScoreNumber >= 2 && skiTimeDecimal <= 50)
                                {
                                    groupLevel = "Intermediate";
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    groupLevel = "Beginner";
                                }

                                fullPupilRecord = fullPupilRecord + "~" + groupLevel;
                                sw.WriteLine(fullPupilRecord);
                                fullPupilRecord = "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

If it helps, here is the code that finds the average between the variables for skiTime:

```
public string CalculateAverage(List<string> skiTime1, List<string> skiTime2, List<string> skiTime3)
    {
        List<string> allValues = new List<string>();
        allValues.AddRange(skiTime1);
        allValues.AddRange(skiTime2);
        allValues.AddRange(skiTime3);
        decimal totalcount = 0;
        decimal average = 0;

        foreach (var value in allValues)
        {
            totalcount = totalcount + decimal.Parse(value);
        }

        average = totalcount / allValues.Count();
        return average.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Well, would it be possible that that `skiTime[i]` is not something that C# can interpret as a decimal? Have you tried printing it out right before that line (or use the debugger in your IDE)?

Comment: According to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?view=net-6.0#system-convert-todecimal(system-string) , Convert.ToDecimal will not throw InvalidCastException.  Generally, a that exception would be where youuse an invalid cast, so something like `(int)"1234"`.

Comment: what does that mean, what is a cast and what makes it invalid?

Comment: Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions to understand casting and when it would be valid or invalid. And when debugging, pay close attention to the full error message and stack trace in the exception: it will tell you exactly which type of object you were trying to cast into which other type, as well as the exact line of code that the invalid cast is happening on.